# How to display relative commit number in git log graph?

Tags: git, logging, mercurial

I'm a **Mercurial** user, who is exploring some code from a **Git** repo. In Mercurial, I like to move up and down a commit graph, doing checkout and running the code to test how the code behavior changes as I move to older/newer commits. This is easy in Mercurial since it has local relative revision numbers, which are plain integers that increment/decrement as I go up and down the log graph. I can quickly see these revision numbers in `hg log`.

I need to do this type of climbing up/down a log graph in Git. Currently, I do this in Git by invoking `git checkout master~1`, `git checkout master~2`, `git checkout master~3` and so on.

This is fine for commits close to the master, but gets complicated when I'm 20 or 100 commits down below master. I feel that it would be easier if I could get `git log` or `git log --graph` to show me the relative commit number (how far is a commit from the master) along with the revision hash.

Something like this (note the `m~1`, `m~2`, numbers below):

```
$ git log --graph --oneline

*   7d49b65 2015-12-01 Merge pull request #538 from erwincoumans/master
|\  
| * 5da9e37 2015-11-26 add BT_DECLARE_ALIGNED_ALLOCATOR()
* |   0f8d94b (m~1) 2015-11-26 Merge pull request #536
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 4c88681 2015-11-26 joint trajectory curves use different colors
|/  
*   3463081 (m~2) 2015-11-24 Merge pull request #535
|\  
| * 0e24726 2015-11-24 use BT_ID_MAX as std::max is not portable
| * e387baf 2015-11-24 add collision and inverse dynamics
* |   a14a695 (m~3) 2015-11-24 Merge pull request
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 4205e97 2015-11-24 another fix for dynamic libs
* |   22e8dc9 (m~4) 2015-11-24 Merge pull request #533
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 5f97a56 2015-11-24 portability issues
* |   af142de (m~5) 2015-11-24 Merge pull request #532
```

Is it possible to get this display in `git log`? Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bash users who might find it useful here is a simple script which displays relative-to-HEAD commit numbers in `git log` for default (full) format as well as `--oneline` format both supporting `--graph` variant:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

fp="--first-parent"
if [[ "$*" =~ --graph ]]; then
    unset fp  # if --graph is among parameters '${fp:+$fp}' below yields nothing (no --first-parent to git log)
fi

n=0
git log --decorate=short --color=always ${fp:+$fp} "$@" |
while IFS="\n" read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^(\*.+)?.\[33m(commit|[0-9a-f]{7}) ]]; then
        line="$line HEAD~$n"  # append relative number at the end of line
        ((n+=1))              # increment number by 1
    fi
    echo "$line"   # print (either modified or untouched) line from git log to the output       
done
```

This script may be put e.g. to `$HOME` directory, I called it: *logn.sh*. While saved (with `chmod +x`) one may declare a git alias referring to it in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
...
[alias]
    logn = "!logn() { ~/logn.sh \"$@\" | less -r; }; logn"
```

`| less -r` is for users who prefer seeing *git log* in a pager (`-r` for preserving colors). This can be removed.

The script relies on the following regex pattern: `^(\*.+)?.\[33m(commit|[0-9a-f]{7})`. The part with `(\*.+)?` is "sneaky" when it comes to `--graph` format because each line with a primary revision (first parent) starts with asterisk `*` so we can utilize this to match correct revisions this way.

`\[33m` is a trick for ensuring we deal with a header (commit SHA) line in every commit entry since it is fed with this color specifier by git (hence `--color=always` in the script) and the rest of the pattern is just a '`commit`' word from that same line OR a direct short-SHA on behalf of `--oneline` format.

Without using `--graph` the script forces `--first-parent` option since sequential HEAD counting would be incorrect / make no sense for non-first-parent commits (from merged branches).

Both the alias (`\"$@\"`) and the script (`"$@"`) forward positional parameters to `git log` command so it works with any other parameters that may be put, like `-p`, `-<n>` (number of shown commits), `--name-only`, mentioned `--oneline`, `--graph`, etc.

If we tamper with the format too much the regex pattern may stop matching and relative numbers won't be appended. And of course relative numbers won't be valid if we pass a non-HEAD revision to start from (e.g. `git logn HEAD^^`, `git logn <non-HEAD-SHA1>`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to decorate a git log with relative HEAD revision.

But the alternative is, once you see the commit you want to checkout in the `git log --graph`, to use its SHA1

```
git checkout af142de # which is m~5
```

From there, you can make additional checkout relative to that SHA1:

```
git checkout af142de~1 # which is m~6
```

Comment: Is there any trick that Git users do to type out a SHA1 without copy-paste with mouse? Mercurial commit integers are easy to see once and type out at the shell.

Comment: @Ash not really. The only trick is that you don't have to type the all 42 bits of the Sha1: only the first 5 to 7 characters are enough

Comment: @AshwinNanjappa Yes, it is. If you use ***tmux*** you can copy/paste any console output phrase easily (using emacs-mode or vi-mode) with a keyboard, not bothering with a mouse or any finger-twisting shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a computer with "nl" and "sed" commands available, try this:

```
git log --first-parent --pretty="%s - %ae" -50 |
        nl -v 0 |
        sed 's/\([0-9].*$\)/HEAD~\1/'
```

Here's top 15 lines of output when run against PHP's git repo:

```
 HEAD~0 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - ab@php.net
 HEAD~1 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - ab@php.net
 HEAD~2 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - ab@php.net
 HEAD~3 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~4 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - ab@php.net
 HEAD~5 fix initializer for empty_fcall_info - ab@php.net
 HEAD~6 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~7 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~8 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~9 Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~10    Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~11    Bump API numbers - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~12    Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - nikic@php.net
 HEAD~13    unpack() function optional argument $offset. - dmitry@zend.com
 HEAD~14    Merge branch 'PHP-7.0' - ab@php.net
 HEAD~15    Removed zend_fcall_info.symbol_table - dmitry@zend.com
```